# Laravel many to many retrieve data across multi table

Tags: php, laravel

[Database Table Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF7gw.png)

What I did:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $company_feedback = $request->user()->company()
   ->get()->pluck('id')-  >toArray();

    $company = Company::whereIn('id',$company_feedback);
    $feedback = $company->feedback;

    return view('feedback.index', ['feedbacks' => $feedback]);

}
```

By using eloquent relationship, how to retrieve feedback data from a specific user id ? I want show feedback data which belong to current login user login id.
anyone could help? show me how to write the code in Index method in Feedback class.

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships. It's all answered in the docs.

Comment: Show us your db structure for the related tables, if you have one.

Comment: in attachment above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two models User.php and Feedback.php

If you want to retrieve all feedback given by a current user

> In your User.php

```
public function feedback()
{
 //assuming you have user_id column in feedback table
 return $this->hasMany("App\Feedback",'user_id');
}
```

> In your controller 
>     //all feedback given by the current user

```
$feedbacks = Auth::user()->feedback;
```

Comment: No, my feedback table doesn't directly belong to user table.

Comment: Explain your question from which all tables you want to collect data

Comment: I want to collect data from feedback that is belong to user table. I mean to show feedback data to a current user login. the feedback data was inserted by anonymous.

Comment: when anonymous do feedback, they'll input title, description and choose companies they want to feedback to.

Comment: You want to show all the feedback related to the logged in user ?

Comment: yeah, I want this

Comment: feedback table contains user_id ?

Comment: I could do it by using query builder but eloquent not.